# Is there any point in encrypting files that users have uploaded to my site?

Tags: security, encryption

This is just a question to put out there as I am unsure if there is a benefit to this or not. However I am thinking about encrypting the files that are uploaded to my site (As they could potentially contain users names and addresses along with some other personal data). However it occurred to me that the only way hackers could get hold of these files would be to gain control of the server and if they did that then they would have access to the encrypted files and also the database connection strings etc. Once they have those then they could easily decrypt the files.

The traffic itself is protected with SSL and I am not interested in using public key encryption as that is not something that would work for the users. So is it worth the extra effort and hassle of encrypting the uploaded files?

Comment: Use an extra pc/server that performs encryption and decryptions that doesn't allow any other connection. This is similar to HSM devices, where the key is inside.

Comment: I do not have that option right now...

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, it is a security related question. I would delete this question and post again in https://security.stackexchange.com/. You'll find much better answers there.